# Who came to know Gollum had once possessed the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring

Related: [Sauron, Gollum, and the Ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47067/sauron-gollum-and-the-ring)

I've always found it interesting that Gollum possessed the One Ring for approximately five hundred years without Sauron sniffing it out; it seems actual talk of the One Ring was extremely minimal, something that only a few might dare speak of behind closed doors in the dead of night or something.

**Once the ring passed to Bilbo, did others begin to learn about Gollum and that he was a ringbearer?** (I realize Bilbo and Gandalf came to know this information). Did the entire Fellowship know Gollum had been a ringbearer, or just a select few in the group? Did anyone outside the Fellowship come to find out?

Comment: One item to note is that Sauron may not have been capable of doing much of anything during the period of time Gollum possessed the ring.

Comment: Eventually, lots of hobbits presumably knew, since it was in the Red Book of Westmarch...

Comment: I felt that my answer covered pretty much all of the bases. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Certainly **Boromir, Legolas and Aragorn** knew that Gollum was a ringbearer;

> Know also, my friends, that I learned more yet from Gollum. He was
>   loth to speak and his tale was unclear, but it is beyond all doubt
>   that he went to Mordor, and there all that he knew was forced from
>   him. **Thus the Enemy knows now that the One is found, that it was long
>   in the Shire; and since his servants have pursued it almost to our
>   door,** he soon will know, already he may know, even as I speak, that we
>   have it here.'
>
> All sat silent for a while, until at length Boromir
>   spoke. **"He is a small thing, you say, this Gollum? Small, but great in
>   mischief. What became of him? To what doom did you put him?"  "He is
>   in prison, but no worse," said Aragorn. "He had suffered much. There
>   is no doubt that he was tormented, and the fear of Sauron lies black
>   on his heart.** Still I for one am glad that he is safely kept by the
>   watchful Elves of Mirkwood. His malice is great and gives him a
>   strength hardly to be believed in one so lean and withered. He could
>   work much mischief still, if he were free. And I do not doubt that he
>   was allowed to leave Mordor on some evil errand." - <sub><sup>LOTR : FOTR</sup></sub>

As did **Gloín** (and possibly his men too);

> Glóin rose and bowed, and Legolas continued. 'In the days of fair
>   weather we led Gollum through the woods; and there was a high tree
>   standing alone far from the others which he liked to climb. Often we
>   let him mount up to the highest branches, until he felt the free wind;
>   but we set a guard at the tree's foot. <sub><sup>LOTR : FOTR</sup></sub>

**Sam** obviously knew;

> “It doesn't sound as if he knew we were here, does it? ' whispered
>   Sam. ”And what's his Precious? Does he mean the...'
>
> “Hsh!' breathed
>   Frodo. ”He's getting near now, near enough to hear a whisper." <sub><sup>LOTR : TTT</sup></sub>

And **Gimli, Glorfindel, Erestor, Erestor and Galdor** (and everyone else who was at the "[Council of Elrond](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Council_of_Elrond)":

> He then pointed out and named those whom Frodo had not met before.
>   There was a younger dwarf at Glóin's side: his son Gimli. Beside
>   Glorfindel there were several other counsellors of Elrond's household,
>   of whom Erestor was the chief; and with him was Galdor, an Elf from
>   the Grey Havens who had come on an errand from Círdan the Shipwright.
>   There was also a strange Elf clad in green and brown, Legolas, a
>   messenger from his father, Thranduil, the King of the Elves of
>   Northern Mirkwood. And seated a little apart was a tall man with a
>   fair and noble face, dark-haired and grey-eyed, proud and stern of
>   glance.
>
> "Very well," said Bilbo. "I will do as you bid. But I will now tell
>   the true story, and if some here have heard me tell it otherwise" – he
>   looked sidelong at Glóin – `I ask them to forget it and forgive me. I
>   only wished to claim the treasure as my very own in those days, and to
>   be rid of the name of thief that was put on me. But perhaps I
>   understand things a little better now. **Anyway, this is what happened.'
>   To some there Bilbo's tale was wholly new, and they listened with
>   amazement while the old hobbit, actually not at all displeased,
>   recounted his adventure with Gollum, at full length.** He did not omit a
>   single riddle. <sub><sup>LOTR : FOTR</sup></sub>

and **Faramir**:

> “He is lured here, you say? ' said Faramir in a low voice. ”Can he,
>   does he then know of your burden? ' “Indeed yes. He bore it himself
>   for many years.” **'He bore it? ' said Faramir, breathing sharply in his
>   wonder. "This matter winds itself ever in new riddles. Then he is
>   pursuing it? '** <sub><sup>LOTR : TTT</sup></sub>

Oh, and **big S** knew;

> Sauron released [Gollum] and sent him forth... He did not trust
>   Gollum, for he divined something indomitable in him, which could not
>   be overcome … except by destroying him. **But Sauron perceived the depth
>   of Gollum's malice towards those that had “robbed” him, and guessing
>   that he would go in search of them…, Sauron hoped that his spies would
>   thus be led to the Ring.**
>
> …Sauron had never paid heed to the “Halflings,” even if he had heard
>   of them, and he did not yet know where their land lay. From Gollum,
>   even under pain, he could not get any clear account, both because
>   Gollum indeed had no certain knowledge himself, and because what be
>   knew he falsified. Ultimately indomitable he was, except by death, as
>   Sauron did not fully comprehend, being himself consumed by lust for
>   the ring. … [Gollum] dared to pretend that he believed that the land
>   the Halflings was near to the .places where he had once dwelt beside
>   the banks of the Gladden. <sub><sup>Unfinished Tales</sup></sub>

Comment: Faramir also found out. '... He bore it himself for many years.' The Forbidden Pool, The Two Towers.

Comment: @IanThompson - When you've got good stuff like this, just add it as an edit :-)

Comment: Don't you mean Legolas, and not Thranduil? Thranduil was not present at the Council and sent his son Legolas as his messenger, as you have stated :-)

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - Oops, yes. I misread that passage.